# Grouping hidden files and directories with ls

Tags: files, ls, sort, dot-files

How can `ls` be flagged to sort `.`-prefixed hidden directories and files in groups so that its output is sorted as visible directories, hidden directories, visible files, then hidden files?

I currently have ls aliased to `ls -lG --color --group-directories-first` which groups directories first, but visible and hidden directories are mixed together.

Instead, the output of `ls` should be:

```
visibleDirectoryA
visibleDirectoryB
.hiddenDirectoryA
.hiddenDirectoryB
visibleFileA
visibleFileB
.hiddenFileA
.hiddenFileB
```

Comment: i can reproduce, with locale `en_AU.UTF8`.     BTW, `LANG=C ls ....` fails to reproduce (and, in fact, will even sort a directory name like `!foo` before any of the .hidden directories - strict ascii value sort rather than a natural sort).

Comment: My locale output is 
`LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `-v` for natural sort.  e.g.

```
ls -lG --color --group-directories-first -A -v
```

Note while they are sorted into their own "group", the .hidden directories will appear **before** the visible directories, not after them, because a `.` sorts lower than most other characters.